# How to call properties of derived class in View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have two models which derives from abstract class, becouse I need to store them in one list and order them by DateTime.
Inheritance looks like this:

```
    public abstract class BaseActivity
    {
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }
    public class Call : BaseActivity
    {
        //props//
    }
    public class Message : BaseActivity
    {
        //props//
    }
```

And now I'm using viewModel with this abstract class as property.

```
    public class ViewModel
    {
        //...other props...//
        public IEnumerable<BaseActivity> BaseActivities { get; set; }
    }
```

The thing is I should now display items from this list, but each type has own properties. Is there any other way to do this than switching by type in view like this?

```
@foreach (var activity in Model.BaseActivities )
{
    switch (activity)
    {
        case Call call:
                 @* display Call properties *@
            break;
        case Message message:
                 @* display Message properties *@
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be far easier having an abstract method in `BaseActivity` called `DisplayProperties()`? The child classes would have its own implementation and show whatever they want

Comment: @Cleptus Sound really great, but  should I mix html syntax into domain models?

Comment: Or maybe mirror whole inheritance into ViewModels and add this method in BaseActivityViewModel?

Comment: Since the abstract class has two derived classes, in the View you have to use a switch or if statement to check the type, then get the related property, unless you do this action on the server side. Besides, if you want to get the property value via the `activity`, you could use the Reflection method, code [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxjjU.png): `<span>@activity.GetType().GetProperty("property name").GetValue(activity, null)</span>`